# TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, bayesian, bayesian-networks

> I get the following error:

> 

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

> for the following code. I'm new to Python and I don't know how to solve it.  Hoping it's a simple fix but don't know enough

```
def get_correct_indices(model, x, labels):
    y_model = model(x)
    correct = np.argmax(y_model.mean(), axis=1) == np.squeeze(labels)
    correct_indices = [i for i in range(x.shape[0]) if correct[i]]
    incorrect_indices = [i for i in range(x.shape[0]) if not correct[i]]
    return correct_indices, incorrect_indices


def plot_entropy_distribution(model, x, labels):
    probs = model(x).mean().numpy()
    entropy = -np.sum(probs * np.log2(probs), axis=1)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4))
    for i, category in zip(range(2), ['Correct', 'Incorrect']):
        entropy_category = entropy[get_correct_indices(model, x, labels)[i]]
        mean_entropy = np.mean(entropy_category)
        num_samples = entropy_category.shape[0]
        title = category + 'ly labelled ({:.1f}% of total)'.format(num_samples / x.shape[0] * 100)
        axes[i].hist(entropy_category, weights=(1/num_samples)*np.ones(num_samples))
        axes[i].annotate('Mean: {:.3f} bits'.format(mean_entropy), (0.4, 0.9), ha='center')
        axes[i].set_xlabel('Entropy (bits)')
        axes[i].set_ylim([0, 1])
        axes[i].set_ylabel('Probability')


        axes[i].set_title(title)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: off-topic, but instead of using `for i, category in zip(range(2), ["Correct", "Incorrect"]):` you can simply use `for i, category in enumerate(["Correct", "Incorrect"]):`

Comment: "I'm new to Python and I don't know how to solve it". So, why are you working with *plotly* and *numpy* when you haven't yet grasped the fundamentals of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your `correct` variable in line 3 is a boolean.

A boolean is not subscriptable, i.e., it is not a storage class, such as Python's `list` object. Thus, you cannot use `[]` to index it (as it is not storing an array of values).

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to execute your code and test it.
However I think you should try to run it, and print all substripted objects in order to debug your code.
I.e. print ´correct’ in your first function
And get_correct_indices in your second function
See what happens…
Otherwise, try sending a code which can be executed for testing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not use `[]` operator with boolean.
The problem seems to be in this two lines:

```py
    correct = np.argmax(y_model.mean(), axis=1) == np.squeeze(labels)
    correct_indices = [i for i in range(x.shape[0]) if correct[i]]
```

See, `correct` is a boolean variable and you try to access it with correct[i]